# Power Up Issues with MacBook Pro A1278

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, power-mac

First-off, let me preface this question by stating that I know nothing to very little about computers, especially Apple computers. That being said, I have a MacBook Pro A1278 model. About a month ago, smoke started coming out of the top row of keys on the keyboard (not good at all - that much I do know); so, I powered it down. Then it would not power up at all. This morning, I tried plugging in the adapter and, lo and behold, it started to fire up. However, the progress bar only moves about a third of the way across before it shuts down again. It does this whether or not the adapter is plugged in or not, so I am thinking that it is not the adapter or the battery. If I continue to hold down the power button, it was going into my Desktop. However, as soon as I release it, within about 2 seconds, it shuts down again. Also, now when I continue to hold the power button down, it only makes it about halfway and then shuts off again.

Could it be my power supply? something else? Any advice would be greatly appreciated as it is a work computer. Thanks.

Comment: If smoke was coming out of the computer, it has been seriously damaged and should not be turned back on. If this is a computer owned by your employer, please contact them about what to do. Please seek professional assistance with this problem, as I doubt there is anything anyone on this site can do for you.

Comment: You let the magic smoke out; you need to take it in for service.

Comment: It sounds like a short to me. I suspect the logicboard has failed.

Answer (score 1):

The smoke coming out of your Macbook would lead anyone to conclude that the problem system had either an:

- Overheating battery (common on some model MBP's)
- Overheating CPU (not at all common unless there is a blockage or other external heat.)

As others have suggested, it is definitely time for you to triage and rescue whatever remains on the HDD and take it to the Apple Store for a further diagnosis. Here are some things you can do in the meantime

- Verify if the battery is the problem. Take a careful look at the chassis of the aluminum unibody. Does it seem swollen in some areas? If you use one finger to press on an edge of the MBP, does it rock? Swollen batteries are a common indicator of battery malfunction.
- If the battery is removable from the bottom of the MBP, go ahead and remove it. Attach the AC adapter and power on your MBP without the battery installed. This should mitigate your device from turning off because of the heat from a malfunctioning battery. Other things you can do is place your device on a cool, dry kitchen counter while running it without the battery. This will further allow you to use the computer without risk of running into the CPU thermal throttling timer (simple function: too hot -> turn off).
- Lastly, if the above tip worked, immediately move your HDD contents to a backup location.

Please report back on your findings and mark answered if this helps.